# EXCEL: How to increment a worksheet but keep the cell reference the same by using autofill?

Tags: excel

Given this formula:

```
='[New Daily Parts Target FY20.xls]FY20 APRIL'!$GO$30
```

I want to be able to drag this cell horizontally and increment the worksheet month by month while keeping the cell reference the same.

As an example:

```
='[New Daily Parts Target FY20.xls]FY20 APRIL'!$GO$30
='[New Daily Parts Target FY20.xls]FY20 MAY'!$GO$30
='[New Daily Parts Target FY20.xls]FY20 JUNE'!$GO$30
```

etc...

Is there an easy way to do this? Currently I have to manually change each cell which is becoming a pain and not feasible long term. I don't have the ability to change the worksheet names from the workbook 'New Daily Parts Target FY20.xls' because it is not my document and is updated every day. I am simply referencing information from that document in mine.

Hopefully someone here came help me with a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use INDIRECT.

Comment: I am aware of the INDIRECT function but can't figure out how to get it to work in my context. In most cases that I've seen, the worksheets are numbered which allows them to be incremented.

Comment: You'd need to build up the month name dynamically with a formula. And I'm assuming FY20 changes to FY21?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Eventually it will change to FY21 but the master document hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: Something like `=TEXT(DATE(2020,COLUMN(D:D),1),"Mmmm")`.

Comment: I think i understand what that equation does but I'm unsure how to relate it to my question. Sorry for my confusion. Just to clarify, the name of each sheet on the master document is FY20 APRIL, FY20 MAY, etc.

Comment: Maybe this is more helpful: `="FY"&UPPER(TEXT(DATE(2020,COLUMN(D:D),1),"Yy Mmmm"))`.

Comment: Okay, your formula will now auto-populate the way that I want it to but I need to integrate it into the original formula. I tried this: `='[New Daily Parts Target FY20.xls]"FY"&UPPER(TEXT(DATE(2020,COLUMN(D:D),1),"Yy Mmmm"))'!$GO$30` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT` and just dynamically build up the year/month portion of the filename:

```
=INDIRECT("'[New Daily Parts Target FY20.xls]FY" & UPPER(TEXT(DATE(2020,COLUMN(D:D),1),"Yy Mmmm")) & "'!$GO$30")
```